# how to start a limited query using the where for mysql and php?

Tags: php, sql

how to start a limited query using the where for mysql and php?

for example, the following query??

```
       $start = 0;
       $range = 10;

       $query = "SELECT column FROM $table LIMIT $start, $range";
```

But what I would like to do is start a Limit $start from a particular column value and increase from there, like this:

```
                          $start = column_value;
```

Comment: SELECT column FROM $table WHERE column_value >= $start?

Answer (score 3):

Add the where clause to your SQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT column 
              FROM $table 
          WHERE column >= $column_value
          LIMIT $start, $range";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need an ORDER BY clause too.

```
$query = "SELECT column
FROM $table            
WHERE column > $column_value           
ORDER BY column
LIMIT $start, $range";
```

Comment: Yes, provided that enough rows are available.  For example, you cannot start at 150, if only 100 row have column > $column_value